# Update form real-time when data is concurrently updated in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, real-time, live

Suppose I have some data similar to the following stored in an array (2D). I allow multiple users to update it concurrently and I want to view it live on a form or whatever I can do so to see real-time updates.

```
1   2   3   4   5   
6   7   8   9   10  
11  12  13  14  15  
16  17  18  19  20  
21  22  23  24  25  
26  27  28  29  30  
31  32  33  34  35
```

Can anyone help me achieve the above task in Java? If there is a good way to do it in another language such as Python, I'd also appreciate it.

Comment: Is your data stored in a database? Is it a web application? Which libraries do you use for displaying that information?

Comment: current I have it on a text file but i'm fine to move it to a database if it makes my life easier. please suggest the best option. thank

Answer (score 0):

You must use the 'synchronized' statment on the method or block wich saves the users changes. It controls the access to the code by allowing only one user executing the whole synchronized block until it finishes.

Here is a link for the document over this with some examples.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that:

- You are okay with the refresh rate being a predefined value in the tens of milliseconds.
- You are okay with users concurrently overwriting each other and updates being lost.
- You are not really interested in squeezing out every ounce of performance from the solution that you'll end up using.
- You are not translating the techniques provided here for different use-cases without understanding how these techniques work internally and modifying them to fit the new requirements.

Having said that, you can simply use a single shared array of `int` elements and a single shared `AtomicLong` tracking its revisions. Then you can allow updates to the array from each concurrent user, just making sure that the `AtomicLong` is incremented on each update from the user.

You can have the UI thread check periodically the shared data by first reading the `AtomicLong`, and then reading the array contents - the length of the period will be determined by the frame rate you want to maintain, but I'd think that 30 milliseconds should be good enough.

You'll be guaranteed to see the thread contents being updated, due to the *happens-before* edge between writes and reads of the `AtomicLong`. Notice that if you want to use an array of `long`s, you'll need to ensure that the writes to each array element will be atomic.

Here's a quick illustration of the principle with some dummy code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public class Playground {

   private static AtomicLong REVISION = new AtomicLong(0);
   private static int[] ARR = new int[10];

   private static final int NUM_THREADS = 100;
   private static final int NUM_UPDATES_PER_THREAD = 100;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Thread(() -> {
         int totalRevs = NUM_THREADS * NUM_UPDATES_PER_THREAD;
         while (REVISION.get() < totalRevs) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ARR));
            try {
               Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (Exception e) {}
         }
      }).start();
      for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i) {
         final int iCopy = i;
         new Thread(() -> {
            for (int j = 0; j < NUM_UPDATES_PER_THREAD; ++j) {
               Random rnd = new Random();
               int sleepTime = rnd.nextInt(100);
               try {
                  Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
               } catch (Exception e) {}
               int index = rnd.nextInt(10);
               int value = rnd.nextInt();
               ARR[index] = value;
               REVISION.incrementAndGet();
            }
         }).start();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: thank for help but my concern is how to render the update output on a form? regards

Comment: @vchar Aha... Well, I'd suggest to re-state this more explicitly in your question and to show your intent by tagging it accordingly. Right now your question deceptively looks like what I was trying to answer :) I'd guess that to solve your problem you'll have much harder time solving its concurrency half than solving its UI half, but on the other hand you'll be asking a broader audience if your concern is about rendering your array in a form.